# where is the "Keep wi-fi on during sleep" settings in Samsung s9?

Tags: wi-fi, samsung, settings, samsung-galaxy-s-9

My Samsung S9 phone wi-fi connection goes off when it goes to sleep mode (after a while whenever the screen turns off ).  I've found there where a setting option called "Keep wifi on during sleep" in the wi-fi settings advanced menu before the Android version 9, but I can't find such an option in my phone setting. It is very annoying nowadays during remote work from home.
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome on the Android SE! I find it surprising - I have never seen such a phone which turns wifi off on sleep. But I experienced many times that the wifi part of my phone far from the typical quality of the laptops. It might be because making a good wifi in the size (and power consumption) requirements of the typical phones is far more hard. Possibly it can be the cause of your problem, i.e. only your wifi connection is sub-optimal, but hopefully you will get an answer, too.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica Hi, I don't think the problem is the wifi connection, there are many other phones in the area with no problem. the main problem is why there is no  "Keep wifi on during sleep" option in phone settings?